# mod_rewrite is being ignored

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to transform "domain.com/index.php?site=food&category=beef" into "domain.com/food/beef" but it does not work, no matter what I try. It always leaves the original domain and I get no errors.

I think it's my fault, I tried this for 3 different URLs on 3 different servers (and 3 different projects)... it just seems like I don't get how mod_rewrite really works, though I read every documentation on this topic I found. I even spent days here on SO without finding any solution.

Mod_rewrite is enabled on the server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^  http://www.google.com [R,L]
```

gives me "http://www.google.com/?site=food&category=beef". It looks like mod_rewrite does not recognise the query string... So I tried several solutions with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}... but nothing works :/

Hopefully you guys can help me! I'm going insane on this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^food/beef$ index.php?site=food&category=beef [L]
```

Or more generally:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?site=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure you request `domain.com/food/beef` and not `domain.com/index.php?site=food&category=beef`, in your browser ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Yes, I want to have domain.com/food/beef instead of the long URL in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?site=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

This will make it so when you go to http://domain.com/food/beef the request gets rewritten to "/index.php?site=food&category=beef" internally and index.php is used to serve the original request. The browser's location bar will still say "http://domain.com/food/beef".

If you want the location bar to say http://domain.com/index.php?site=food&category=beef then add an "R," to the "[L]". If this is backwards and you want it so when someone enters http://domain.com/index.php?site=food&category=beef in the location bar, and the request gets rewritten to "/food/beef" internally on the server, then you need to parse out the query string using RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=([^&]+)&category=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2? [L]
```

The same thing applies with the "R" causing a browser redirect like the first example. If you want the location bar to change to http://domain.com/food/beef then the brackets should look like: `[L,R]`. Note that you need a **?** at the end of the target in the rule, so that query strings don't get thrown in. That is why in your google example, the query string is being appended.

EDIT:

### Seeing as you just wanted to change what's in the browser's location bar and not where the content is:

You need to **re-rewrite** what the 2nd rule above has rewritten **BACK** to index.php, but without a redirect. In order to keep the 2 rules from looping indefinitely because one rule rewrites to the other rule and vice versa, you need to add a flag somewhere to keep the 2nd rule above from redirecting you over and over again.

So combining the two, you'll have this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?site=$1&category=$2&redirected [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirected
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=([^&]+)&category=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Note the `redirected` parameter in the query string. This gets inserted when someone tries to access the clean version of the url, e.g. "/food/beef". internally, it gets rerouted to index.php but since the rule doesn't have a "R", the browser's location bar doesn't change.

The second rule now checks if the request contains the `redirected` param in the query string. If it doesn't, that means someone entered in their browser's location bar the index.php url, so redirect the browser to the clean version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried both with [L] and [L,R] but the browser bar is still showing "domain.com/index.php?site=food&category=beef" and yes, I want it to display "domain.com/food/beef"

Comment: The second doesn't redirect for you? If you use the 2nd rule, don't include the first one, they aren't compatible together. You don't have any other rules that might affect this, do you?

Comment: No, except the 2nd rule the .htaccess is blank. There is no redirect, just nothing happens :/

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On`? (I left that out, thought it was redundant)

Comment: Yes, my .htaccess looks like this:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=([^&]+)&category=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2? [L,R]`

Comment: Ahh, it comes closer! The URL changes to http://domain.com/food/beef but I get this error "The requested URL /food/beef was not found on this server." instead of the content.

Comment: Where is the content if it's not at `htmlroot/food/beef`? Is it being served by index.php (which you've redirected AWAY from)?

Comment: Yes, the content is a php file which is included into the index.php via require_once from htmlroot/inc.

Comment: See the edit above. Had no idea you wanted to redirect the browser to a non-existent location. There was no indication in your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought mod_rewrite could just "rename" what's displayed in the browser bar, I didn't know that a redirect is required :/

After using the code from your edit the css styles don't apply anymore. When I type domain.com/food/beef/ I see the plain, unformatted html content and when I click on e.g. "fish" in the subnavigation it redirects me to "domain.com/food/index.php?site=food&category=fish" :/

Comment: It's probably because all the links are relative paths, which means when the browser's location bar says "domain.com/food/beef/" and the link is "style.css", browser attempts to load "domain.com/food/beef/style.css", all the links need to be absolute if you want to rewrite the location bar like this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, they are all relative... I tought I already changed them to absolute (at least the css files)... It's my fault again. Is this URL "domain.com/food/index.php?site=food&category=fish" also caused by relative links?

Comment: Converting relative to absolute paths didn't work. I found out that I can't point to css in my /css dir files or images in my /img dir, it always displays the html content from home instead of the image but shows the correct file path in the URL bar.